# How to redirect STDOUT of a program to STDIN of a GDB-debugged program?

Tags: python, c, gdb

I normally redirect STDOUT to another program using:

`python -c 'print("HelloWorld")' | ./myprog`

I know that I can supply the contents of a file as STDIN for a debugged program in GDB:

`(gdb) run myprog < input.txt`

However, how can I do something like:

`(gdb) run mypprog < python -c 'print("HelloWorld")'`

without first having to create a file with the output of `python -c '...'`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to attach gdb to your already-running process. Find its pid with `ps` or `top`. Let's say that it's 37. Then run

```
(gdb) attach 37
```

That probably won't work for your case with very short run time though. Another approach is to use a [fifo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo).

```
mkfifo fifo
python -c 'print("Hello World")' > fifo &
gdb myprog
run < fifo
```

Comment: Say, I attach to the process. How would I then send input to the process?

Comment: If you run something like `python generate_lots_of_data.py | ./process-to-debug` it's already got input going to it. If you only want to send input to the process when you're ready for it, use the fifo approach.

Comment: Thank you - so you cannot interact with the application unless you use a FIFO? (I.e. send input at different points in the execution)

Comment: If you interact with it directly, you can attach gdb to the running process. For example, you could run `cat` in one terminal and attach gdb to it in another. Since `cat` is just sitting there waiting for input, you can manually send it something and watch it get processed. For programmatic output, though, you'll want a FIFO.